# Creating histogram with different column styles and different labels at the bottom

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm wondering how can I achieve such a type of histogram by using `matplotlib` or `seaborn`.
I'm particularly interested in different column styles  and different labels at the bottom.

[image]

Image taken from the paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-020-00352-0.pdf

Comment: That's a bar chart, not a histogram. And yes, very doable.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function recently that does something similar using matplotlib. It takes a pandas dataframe and basically just draws a lot of bars. It's not perfect and fairly specific to my specific needs so you probably need to adapt it to make it look exactly as you intended. There could definitely be a better way, but this might be a pretty good start.

```
def groupbar(ax,data,x,y,hue,colors=[],fs=14,rot=0,ha='center'):
    """
    groupbar(ax,data,x,y,hue,colors=[],fs=14,rot=0,ha='center')
    ax is the axis to plot onto
    data is a pandas dataframe with columns that have the same names as x, y, and hue
    colors is a list of colors to use for the bars
    x is the column name that corresponds to the categories at the bottom
    y is the column that corresponds to the bar height
    hue is the column that corresponds to the subgroup (bar color)
    colors is a list of colors for the bars
    fs, rot, and ha are tick label font size, rotation, and horizontal alignment
    """
    xs = data[x].unique()
    hues = np.unique(data[hue])
    Nx = len(xs)
    Nh = len(hues)
    width = (Nh+1)*Nx+1
    handles = []
    xvals = np.zeros((Nx,Nh))
    for xi in range(Nx):
        for hi in range(Nh):
            yval = data[(data[x]==xs[xi])&(data[hue]==hues[hi])][y].values
            xval = (hi+1)*(Nx) + xi + hi
            hand = ax.bar(x=xval,height=yval,width=0.95,color=colors[xi])
            handles.append(hand)
            xvals[xi,hi] = xval
    ax.legend(handles[::Nh],xs,fontsize=16)
    ax.set_xticks(np.median(xvals,0))
    ax.set_xticklabels(hues,fontsize=fs,rotation=rot,ha=ha)
    ax.set_axisbelow(True)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y',labelsize=fs)
    ax.grid(color=[0.8,0.8,0.8],linestyle='--')
    return handles
```

Here's an example assuming you have a pandas dataframe `data` that has columns that specify the category on the bottom, the ('x'), the bar height ('percentage'), and the bar category ('category'), then:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = ['blue','lightblue','darkgoldenrod','gold']
groupbar(ax,data,'x','percentage','category',colors=colors)
```